# Wordpress blog - Removing multiple URLs

Tags: wordpress, url, seo

I have a blog hosted on Wordpress [Technowide](http://technowide.net) with Reading setting as Homepage as Posts page i.e. I have made the home page http://technowide.net/home/ as my blog post page as the result all my blogs listing is displayed on my home page itself along with post navigation.

This resulted in duplicating of URLs with same blog listings.
For example: Both the below URLs show same latest 10 blogs:

http://technowide.net/

http://technowide.net/home/

Same is the case with following pair with next 10 latest posts:

http://technowide.net/home/page/2/

http://technowide.net/page/2/

and so on.

Can anybody please assist me to address this issue??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour is for the homepage to show your latest posts (blog). If that's what you're aiming for change "Front page displays" to "Your latest posts".

The problem you have at the moment is caused by setting the Blog posts page to a page titled Home which I presume is supposed to be the homepage.